# QAction vs QToolButton and when to override the Basic class?

Tags: qt

I've recently been studying Qt, and have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between `QAction` and `QToolButton`?
2. How do I know when to override `QPushButton`? For example, should I override in order to be informed when the mouse enters a `QPushButton`'s bounds? I don't need to in order to get the `signal` `click()`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems to be a pretty valid (although unresearched) request for help from a new user...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1:**

`QAction`s are used to define tasks performed by an application in a way which can be understood by a number of different user interface objects. Using an [example from the Qt docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-application.html) for context:

A `QAction` is defined; it is given an icon image, a text description, a keyboard shortcut and a longer tooltip description, as well as being linked to a user defined function.

```
newAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/new.png"), tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
```

Later in the implementation, the `QAction` is added both to a textual menu bar...

```
fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
```

... and an icon-based tool bar:

```
fileToolBar->addAction(newAct);
```

The menu bar uses the text description to create an entry in the menu corresponding to the action. Similarly the toolbar uses the icon set on the `QAction` to create an icon in the toolbar which corresponds to the action. Selecting the menu item, clicking the toolbar icon or pressing the keyboard shortcut will all result in the same effect: that defined by the linking of `QAction::triggered()` to `newFile()`.

**So to directly answer your question: a `QAction` is an *abstract* way of defining the various parameters and behaviour of a particular task performed by the application. A `QToolbarButton` is a UI object (derived from `QWidget`) created by a `QToolbar` in response to `QToolbar::addAction()`**

---

**Question 2:**

Yes, `QPushButton` has a [`clicked()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) `signal` inherited from `QAbstractButton`, but it does indeed lack a way to inform when the mouse has entered its bounds. You have a couple of options in order achieve this, but first you need to first set the [`mouseTracking`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) property to be enabled. This will allow you to receive mouse move events  on the `QPushButton` even if no mouse buttons are pressed. With that done you need to explore one of the following options:

1. As you suggest, you could subclass `QPushButton` and reimplement [`mousePressEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) in order to respond to the mouse position.
2. You could install another widget as an [`eventFilter`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the `QPushButton`, and watch for events of type (`QEvent::MouseMove`).